# Examples of short English presentations about computer science with advanced English

Tags: resource-request, self-learning, english, exams, specialist-vocabulary

I will have English exam in few days. I am preparing for one part of exam – 12 minutes long oral presentation. Presentation should summarize some text with topic connected to computer science based on longer text. It should contain a lot of phrases showing advanced vocabulary and use of English. I couldn't find any examples of such presentation on the internet. I have found a lot of videos with not so advanced English about computer science and videos with advanced English but about different topics or duration. Could someone recommend me exemplary presentations? It would be the best if it would include source text, video, text of presentation and explanations about used phrases, structure etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small number of computer science conferences record videos of the talks.  One I presented at was [Massive Storage Systems
and Technology (MSST 2016)](https://storageconference.us/2016/) (although I don't think my video is available).  The plenary-talk videos are available [here](https://insidehpc.com/2016-msst-conference-video-gallery/).

For example, [*Workflow Specification for Large-Scale Computational Systems*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YUXrVjPhfs) by David Montoya (with accompanying [talk slides](https://storageconference.us/2016/Slides/DaveMontoya.pdf)) might be appropriate.  It's fairly high-level without an overwhelming amount of technical jargon.

Answer (score -1):

I have hard time believing that you cannot find computer-related presentations on the web. Just google any relevant compsci terms.

If you want video, youtube has zillions, and TED talks https://www.ted.com/recommends has thousands more.

For plain slides, google I.e. "slideshow archives" - slideshare.net looks promising, there are more.

Comment: Note that the question is about computer science, not computers in general.